# angular material - sidenav from the bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-material, sidebar

Angular material sidenav seems to have a **left/right options**:

- `&lt;md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-**right**"&gt;`
- `&lt;md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-**left**"&gt;`

Although it is called a **"side"-nav,** is it possible to use it as a **"bottom"-nav?**

if so how can it be done?

Comment: show us what exactly your requirement is? some code or fiddle?

Answer (score 4):

there is no bottom-nav as you said, but you can do it using https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/bottomSheet

**VIEW**

```
<div class="bottom-sheet-demo inset" layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center" >
    <md-button flex="50" class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showBottomSheet()">Show</md-button>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.showBottomSheet = function() {
    $scope.alert = '';
    $mdBottomSheet.show({
      templateUrl: 'bottom-sheet-template.html',
      controller: 'BottomSheetCtrl'
    }).then(function(clickedItem) {
      $scope.alert = clickedItem['name'] + ' clicked!';
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

angular material does not support bottom nav .. you have to achieve it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are trying to achieve can  be done by overwriting angular material styles to suit your needs. Just add some custom class or id to `<md-sidenav>` element and apply your styles.